# Clearing the selected date of jquery date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a html page where there are numerous instances of jquery date picker.

The problem that I am facing is once I select a date of any one of the instances of the jquery date picker, it gets selected for all the other instances too, even when I am setting the selected date for each of the instances individually from jquery by using the command:
`$('#textBoxID').dpSetSelected(DateVal);`.

So please let me know where I am wrong and also let me know how to clear the selected date and reassign it to the date I wish to assign.

Comment: please mention the `datepicker source website`, because there are a lots of datepicker in this era

Comment: guess: you must have same `id` for all datepicker instance

Comment: @diEcho the `datepicker source website` is http://www.kelvinluck.com/projects/jquery-date-picker

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this issue, make sure the IDs are unique. You may as well try the jQuery UI datepicker (that automatically binds to all text boxes with a user defined class/ID and has good cross browser support): http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Add it to your textBox by using:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

Make sure the textbox classes include datepicker.